# How to convert DOM data into a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have some inputs inside my document like snippet code bellow. I want to make an string or JSON from all inputs per their name and value.

```js
var arr= [];
$('ul li input').each(function(){    
    let name = $(this).attr('name');
    let value = $(this).val();
    arr.push({
        [name] : value 
    })
});   
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input name="SyslogType" type="text" value="asd"/>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input name="timestamp_from" type="text" value="1398/10/03 00:00:00"/>
        <input name="timestamp_to" type="text" value="1398/10/03 00:00:00"/>      
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the result I get:

```
[
  {
    "SyslogType": "asd"
  },
  {
    "timestamp_from": "1398/10/03 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "timestamp_to": "1398/10/03 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

But the thing I want is something like this:

```
{"SyslogType":"asd","timestamp_from":"1398/10/03 00:00:00","timestamp_to":"1398/10/12 00:00:00"}
```

Comment: You **Push** data to **array** but expect **object** !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code.

```js
var json = {};
$('ul li input').each(function(){    
    let name = $(this).attr('name');
    let value = $(this).val();
    json[name] = value;
});   
console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind that is you are using an array and `push()`. Instead you can operate with an empty object `{}`.

So you can add properties to that object, instead using `push` into an array, like the following:

```js
var obj = {};
$('ul li input').each(function(){    
    let name = $(this).attr('name');
    let value = $(this).val();
    obj[name] = value;
});   
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input name="SyslogType" type="text" value="asd"/>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input name="timestamp_from" type="text" value="1398/10/03 00:00:00"/>
        <input name="timestamp_to" type="text" value="1398/10/03 00:00:00"/>      
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Suggested article: [Working with objects from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

I hope that helps!

Comment: I'm impressed.awesome!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 standard methods to get all the form data instantly.
Hope it will help you.

```js
var formData = $('form').serialize();
console.log(formData)

var formDataArray = $('form').serializeArray();
console.log(formDataArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<form>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input name="SyslogType" type="text" value="asd"/>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input name="timestamp_from" type="text" value="1398/10/03 00:00:00"/>
        <input name="timestamp_to" type="text" value="1398/10/03 00:00:00"/>      
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```